# Using jquery, how to close pop-up modal (ui-bootstrap) dynamically without click event in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

:Modal

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="create.html">
<div ng-controller="CreateCampaignCtrl" id="createModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
       heading
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       ----
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit_form()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>create method</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

:controller

```
function CreateCampaignCtrl($scope, $http){       
$scope.submit_form = function(){
        $http({
            url: url,
            data: {},
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function(data){
                $('#createModal').modal('hide');
                alert(data);
        }).error(function(err) { alert('ERROR err');})
    }
};
```

};

The above modal is opened on make ajax request on click of button now i wanted to close this modal dynamically after getting response from server.

Comment: why don't you try `$modalInstanse.close()` inside angular controller code?

Comment: Hello Pankaj, I tried by using this method but it is not working. Thanks for your response.

Comment: are you using `angular-ui-bootstrap`/jQuery `bootstrap` modal?

Comment: I m using angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: then `$modalInstanse.close()` should work..may be you missed `$modalInstanse` in your controller.. could you create a plunkr with problem?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=CabmDBdN1xf5kLIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

Ok scrap my first idea. It really is as simple as

```
modalInstance.close()
```

I just created a 2 second timeout to simulate your promise.

```
$timeout(function(){modalInstance.close();},2000);
```

plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:0P69y4ecz9V8xpi1AFqM?p=preview)

Comment: Hello Lee, thanks for your response, i tried by using $('#id).modal('close') its not closing the modal instead it trows error.

Comment: @VenkateshS don't suppose you could provide the error?

Comment: TypeError: data[option] is not a function

Comment: Thanks for your response, finally i got solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solutions to close UI-Bootstrap POP-UP Modal in angularjs :

```
function getRetiredData($scope, $http, $modalStack){
    $http({
        url : base_url,
        data : {},
        method : "POST",
        headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function(data){
        $modalStack.dismissAll();
    }).error(function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
};
```

};

Inject $modalStack in your controller and call the function like this $modalStack.dismissAll(); it close all the opened modal.